# Understand Miller's algorithm for elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand Miller's algorithm for Weil pairing.
  My goal is to build a rational function $f$ by it's divisor $div(f) = \sum n_P(P).$
  I know that if we have divisors $D_1, D_2$  and rational functions $f_1, f_2$ that satisfy this relations
  $$D_1 = (P_1) - (\mathcal O) + div(f_1) $$
  $$D_2 = (P_1) - (\mathcal O) + div(f_2) $$
  Then we can easy get function $f_1f_2f_3$ and point $P_3 = -(P_1 + P_2)$ that satisfy relation of the same form
  $$D_1 + D_2 = (P_3) - (\mathcal O) + div(f_1f_2f_3) $$
  So rewriting $div(f) = \sum\limits_{P \ne \mathcal O} n_P((P)-(\mathcal O))$ and using double-and-sum algorithm,
  we can build $f$ if we for any $P$, such that $n_P \ne 0$, know $f_P$ and $Q_P$ that satisfy 
  $$(P)-(\mathcal O) = (Q_P) - (\mathcal O) + div(f_P) $$
  My question is how could I get this $f_P$ and $Q_P$?

Comment: I am not a native speaker, so don't hesitate to critique my spelling.